# How do I deploy a Scala application on Google App with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, scala

I'm trying to create a Scala project that I can then deploy on Google App with Eclipse. The problem is I can't add Scala classes in a Google App project and I can't make the Google App plugin recognize my Scala project as a Google project. How is that being done? I'm a beginner programmer and I need it for a project. If this can't be done with Eclipse, what should I use instead?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure latest Scala IDE is installed.
- Create a normal Google App Engine project same way as you would for Java.
- Add Scala nature to the project (in project context menu: Configure/Add Scala
  Nature)

This should be enough. Scala files will compile same way Java files would.